# How do I make my chrome extension so that it works correct?

Tags: javascript

I am making a Chrome extension so you can download images when clicking on them. The problem is that it is a bit buggy, so any help would be awesome. Here is the Javascript:

```
var myImg = document.querySelector('img');
myImg.addEventListener("click", () => {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = myImg.src;
  a.download = myImg.src;
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
});
```

I would assume that maybe you should add an id to the image that the user clicks on, then download the value of the id. But I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: In what way is it buggy?

Comment: If we don't know what's wrong with it how can we try to help fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click on any `img`, you will want to use `querySelectorAll` to capture ALL images on the page, `querySelector` just grabs one.

```
var myImgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
myImgs.forEach(function(img) {
  img.addEventListener("click", (el) => {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = el.target.src;
    a.download = el.target.src;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but for some reason it does not work on every image, but it is better that before. Is there anything wrong with my code that you can see?

Comment: @Landon, your code only accesses one image since `querySelector` only refers to one. Also, another problem could simply be how and when the images are added to code, plus if they are wrapped by links or have event listeners already